# "which a life of Patriotism eminently entitles and quallifies, to enjoy." - Letter from March 6th 1797 by Oliver Ellsworth

Tags: meaning-in-context

> With the same ardour that I have sought the felicity and glory of your Administration, do I now implore for you in repose, those sublime pleasures from a review of the past and perspective of the future, **which a life of Patriotism eminently entitles and quallifies**, *to enjoy*.
>   Source: [1797 Letter from Oliver Ellsworth (3rd Chief Justice of the US) to George Washington](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aOliver_Ellsworth_George_Washington.jpg)

First, why did Ellsworth precede the verb ("to enjoy") with the predicate ("those sublime pleasurse ... entitles and quallifies") ?

I register that this is a letter from 1797 but would like a deeper explanation. I then moved "to enjoy" to a modern position :

> 1. With the same ardour that I have sought the felicity and glory of your Administration, do I now implore for you in repose *to enjoy*, those sublime pleasures from a review of the past and perspective of the future, **which a life of Patriotism eminently entitles and quallifies**.

Second, I'm still muddled by the bolded phrase. Shouldn't the verbs be "entitle TO" and "quallify (ie qualify) FOR" ? The verbs with no prepositions afterwards sound deficient :

> 1. With the same ardour that I have sought the felicity and glory of your Administration, do I now implore for you in repose *to enjoy* those sublime pleasures **which a life of Patriotism eminently entitles YOU TO and quallifies YOU FOR**. from a review of the past and perspective of the future.

---

**Supplement to Andrew Leach's Answer:**

1. Could you please demystify how and why "*to enjoy*" should succeed
   "those sublime pleasures ... **which a life of ... entitles and qualifies**",
   and NOT precede it?
2. How and why did Ellsworth omit "YOU" as the direct object of **entitles and quallifies**?
3. How can I make sense of #1 in my second box, if I wanted to position "to enjoy" before  "those sublime pleasures ... **which a life of ... entitles and qualifies**" ?

In other words, is it possible to construe Ellsworth's writing with "*to enjoy*" before "those sublime pleasures ..." ?

I don't apprehend why, but possibly due to bias towards my first impression, I still think this conceivable.

Answer (score 1):

It's moving the *to enjoy* which has introduced the difficulty with *entitle* and *qualify*. Ellsworth says that Washington is ***entitled and qualified to enjoy*** those sublime pleasures.

The original appears almost illiterate to modern eyes, but perhaps it could be modernised relatively simply by re-arranging the punctuation. A further improvement would be to explicitly add the implied *you*:

> > With the same ardour that I have sought the felecity and glory of your Administration: do I now implore for you in repose, those sublime pleasures from a review of the past and perspective of the future, which a life of Patriotism eminently entitles and quallifies, to enjoy. [[source]](http://founders.archives.gov/documents/Washington/06-01-02-0005)
>
> With the same ardour that I have sought the felecity and glory of your Administration do I now implore for you, in repose, those sublime pleasures from a review of the past and perspective of the future which a life of Patriotism eminently entitles and quallifies you to enjoy.
>
> “Just as I have sought good things for your administration in the past, so do I now earnestly pray that you gain those great pleasures which your life of patriotism eminently entitles and qualifies you to enjoy.”

Comment: Many thanks. +1. Could you please respond to my 3 supplementaries in my OP? Please feel free to add to your answer as answers are easier to read than comments.